# Detect wifi disabled in background with Android O

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

This has been asked before in various forms, but this is the reverse of most of them. I want to be able to detect when the user **disabled** the wifi, and then do something (such as pop a notification reminding them to enable)

Prior to Android O, I could create a broadcast receiver for the wifi state changed intent, but this is no longer the case. I looked around at the alternatives and there does not appear to be a way to detect wifi disabled.

With the native/firebase job scheduling, I can detect when the wifi comes back on. I could also create a foreground service, but this seems both overkill and annoying with a notification.

The other alternative is also heavy, and that is to schedule a repeating job/alarm to periodically check for wifi connectivity. I can use alarms and not wake the device, so that is not as heavy as a service, but still feels a bit heavy.

Is there a way to be notified that wifi was disabled from the background?